# perl - array from input to columns

Tags: perl

I have been trying to do this and I know I am doing it wrong however if someone could possibly assist with a pointer I would appreciate it. What I am trying to do is take a list of filenames from a text file pipe them to stat through a for loop then have perl parse the lines into columns something like this:

List contains:

```
/home/hack/public_html/.htaccess
/home/hack/public_html/index.php
/home/hack/public_html/list
```

I know this can completely be done in perl but I explicitly need to pipe the output to perl
like so:

```
for i in $(cat list); do stat $i | perl -wnl -e '@file=split /File:/ print @file;';done
```

Ideally I would like to get the output from stat like so:

```
File: `.htaccess'
Size: 177           Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 5dh/93d Inode: 159909615   Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (  503/    hack)   Gid: (  503/    hack)
Access: 2013-02-24 15:09:41.000000000 -0600
Modify: 2013-02-10 14:24:04.000000000 -0600
Change: 2013-02-24 15:09:42.000000000 -0600
```

but I only need the following in the arranged column order:

```
File: (the filename) Modify:(dates) Change:(dates) IO Block: (number)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here `@file` contains the data from given file. Now you can work on `@file` and search for the required data by `grep`, `split` or `pattern matching`, store grepped data in some variables and print those variables in whatever order you want.